# How to set the search url?

Tags: android, webview

i came across a problem with the url for google search.

Actually, I have a string and I need to use the string search in google using webview. Unfortunately, the webview shows nothing. Can anyone help?

```
public class viewPage extends Activity {

  WebView mWebView;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.searchonwebview);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String result = intent.getStringExtra("result");

    String url = "http://www.google.com/"+result+" pdf";
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

  }

  private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return true;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: try url with Http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q= + result

Answer (score 0):

Why you are setting

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

After loading the url? It should be before loading url.

```
    String url = "http://www.google.com/"+result+" pdf";
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: i follow the android developer website.